# Generalized expression for waiting time.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution, exponential-sum

In a certain system, a customer must first be served by **server 1** and then by **server 2**. The service times at server ***i*** are Exponential with rate $μ_i$ , i = 1, 2. An arrival finding **server 1** busy waits in line for that server. Upon completion of service at **server 1**, the customer either enters service with **server 2** if **server 2** is free or else queues up behind server 2 until server 2 is free. Customers depart the system after being served by server 2. Suppose that when you arrive there are ***i*** customers in queue in front of **server 1** and ***j*** customers in queue in front of **server 2** . What is the expected total time you spend in the system? At the instant **t=0**, both the servers just began serving the customers.

**Note:** I want to derive a general expression for the waiting time for any value of ***i*** and ***j***. Doing it for ***i*** and ***j*** equals 1~2 is easy.

**My approach for *i=1, j=0*:**

E[time] = E[time waiting at 1] + 1/μ1
+ E[time waiting at 2] + 1/μ2.

Now, E[time waiting at 1] = 1/μ1 ,
E[time waiting at 2] = (1/μ2) $\frac{μ1}{μ1 + μ2}$. The last equation follows by conditioning on whether or not the customer waits for server 2 (finds a customer being served by server 2.)
Therefore,
E[time] = 2/μ1 + (1/μ2)[1 + μ1/(μ1 + μ2)]

**My approach for generalized expression:**

E[time] = E[time waiting at 1] + 1/μ1
+ E[time waiting at 2] + 1/μ2.

Now, E[time waiting at 1] = *i*/μ1 since ***i*** customers are in front of the arriving customers at server 1.

E[time waiting at 2] = $\sum_{n=1}^{i+j}(n/μ2)$(Pr{Arriving customer finds ***n*** customers at ***server 2*** after being served at ***server 1***}).

**P.S.:** I'm having difficulty in determining the probability that arriving customer finds ***n*** customers at ***server 2*** after being served at ***server 1***.

Comment: Tip: Focus on the **expected time** it takes for all $(i+j)$ customers ahead of you to pass through server 2 ($Y$).  Compare with how long you expect to *wait and pass* through server 1 $(X)$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp can you please elaborate a bit. I couldn't get your point.

Comment: Your expected time is the minimum of (A) the expected time for $i$ people clear server 1 and you pass through both servers, and (B) the expected time for $i+j$ people clear server 2 and you to pass through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect to take $X(i)$ to pass through server 1.   That is the expected time for both you and the $i$ people already there to pass through.

Now, you can expect it to take $Y(i+j)$ for server 2 to process the $(i+j)$ people ahead of you.   This will either be completed by the time you reach server 2 (when $X(i)\geqslant Y(i+j)$), or you would need to wait until it does (when $Y(i+j)>X(i)$).

Either way, you can then expect to take an additional $\mu_2^{-1}$ to pass through service 2 yourself.

So the expected time for you to pass through both servers will be $\bbox[lemonchiffon, 1ex]{\max\{X(i),Y(i+j)\}+\mu_2^{-1}}$ .

Evaluate $X(i)$ and $Y(i+j)$.

Comment: I think it will be the maximum of the 2 expressions. Thanks a lot for the help.